# how to ignore exit status from shell command in perl script

Tags: perl, exit-code, filehandler, exitstatus

I have a following code, where i use a command which is used as input for file open.

when my command $cmd gives non-zero exit status my script exits. i want it to still continue and do rest of the things in the script

```
$cmd = 'ps -u psharma';
open( my $fh, "-|",$cmd ) || die( "$cmd failed: $!" );
my @lines = <$fh>;
close($fh) || die $! ? "Close for $cmd failed: $!" : "Exit status $? from command $cmd";
```

Comment: Your last die statement is very ambiguous. It looks as it either checks the return value of `die $!` or selects a string as argument to die. Either way, the script still dies if the close fails. How did you expect it not to?

Comment: i actually wanted to check, whether the error was thrown by the non-zero exit status of $cmd or Close() filehandler. The intension behind doing all this is to make sure the rest part of the script is executed even if exit status of $cmd is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using die, try using [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) to warn you that it did not exit successfully.  It will still continue the script.

```
carp ("Did not exit command successfully!\n") if (! close ($fh) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the whole script, then it terminates at the last line if execution of cmd returned non-zero.
If you want to continue execution beyond this code, then shouldn't you remove die at the last line?

Answer (score 0):

[You can wrap everything in an `eval` block and check the "magic variable" `$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), like so:

```
use strict; #always
use warnings; #always

my $cmd = 'ps -u psharma';

my $fh; #defining outside the scope of the eval block
my @lines; #ditto

eval {
    open $fh, "-|", $cmd 
        or die "$cmd failed: $!";

    @lines = <$fh>;
    close $fh
        or die $!
               ? "Close for $cmd failed: $!"
               : "Exit status $? from command $cmd";
}

if($@) {

    warn "Something bad happened: $@\n";
}
#If you made it here with no warning, then everything's okay.
```

You can also check out [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny), which allows for basic `try/catch/finally` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
close($fh) || die $! ? "Close for $cmd failed: $!" : "Exit status $? from command $cmd";
```

This code already checks for $!/$? (errno/$cmd exit status). So you can just move `die` deeper:

```
close($fh) || $! 
    ? die "Close for $cmd failed: $!" 
    : warn "Exit status $? from command $cmd";
```

However, I think an explicit `if` could be more readable here.